# Read file change in php (linux equivalent of tail -f )

Tags: php

I need to monitor the access.log of a website. I can use the unix `tail -f` in my php but the problem is that when the http server is restarted, the file is truncated and the read stops.

I need this feature in php.

Comment: you probably missed something in your question. it's not clrear, what functionality are you trying to achieve. is it some web online monitor with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using tail -F not -f -- this way it'll continue to monitor the file even if the file is truncated or deleted. it's not the best way though but saves the day.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it, but maybe [Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) can help you:

> inotify is a Linux kernel subsystem that acts to extend filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those changes to applications.

There's a php extension for inotify, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php

Comment: No sollution without adding a new extension?